# Relay: rerender view partially

Tags: relayjs, relay

I have 3 components: ParentContainer, Filter and SearchResults

In order to perform search request I need to change query variables and as far as I understand it's possible only from parent to children. So ParentContainer should be a RootContainer.

But now in case of refetching, everything inside of ParentContainer will be replaced with renderLoading.
But for Filter it doesn't make sense (it remains static)

Is there any better solution in terms of Relay?